# require_eq! macro not working

Tags: anchor

I am trying to use the following code but it isn't working:

`require_eq!(self.state,TokenState::Initial,TokenError::NotAtInitialState);`

This is error I see when `anchor build` is run:

```
require_eq!(game_data.state,TokenState::Initial,TokenError::NotAtInitialState);
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `game::TokenState` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
```

However, the same code works if I use require! macro:

`require!(self.state == TokenState::Initial,TokenError::NotAtInitialState);`

Is it because I am not using a particular trait required for the custom type? If yes then what is this trait?

Comment: What's the type of the values you're comparing

Comment: can you elaborate "not working"?  stating explicitly how you believe it should work and what you're observing instead would be helpful

Comment: @Ademola it is a custom enum TokenState.

Comment: @trent.sol I have updated the error in the question, thanks.

Comment: Ah I see. Looks like your question's gotten a satisfactory answer though. You could probably close this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `game::TokenState` cannot be formatted with the default formatter

Deep in the bowels of `require_eq!()`, `to_string()` is called on your type `TokenState`. This method requires that the [`std::fmt::Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) trait be implemented on `TokenState`.